# Reducing Dissertation Page Count through Font and Formatting Adjustments

Tags: fonts, koma-script, font-encodings, scrreprt

I need help with setting the appropriate font to reduce the overall page count.

Context:
I have been writing my dissertation (on and off) for 8 years now. Unfortunately, I am no longer fully aware of all the packages and settings I have used over the years. I have removed all packages that do not seem relevant for the MWE below. Please forgive me if some packages do not make complete sense or are not up to date - I want to invest as little effort as possible now because:

The dissertation was reviewed by the doctoral office but returned for being too long. I was asked to significantly reduce the number of pages within a few weeks. Time is running out.

In addition to content reductions already made, I am trying to reduce mainly through font size (from 12pt to 11pt), page margins (to div=12, which I still find acceptable), and lastly font type.
By changing the font from serif to sans serif with:

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

I was able to reduce the number of pages by some.
In doing so, I noticed (after converting the .pdf to a Word file) that the body text and (chapter or section) headings, as well as headers, have different fonts:

Headings: Arial

Body text: Lucida Sans Unicode

Headers: Calibri

For the first submission, I had changed the headers to bold using the following command:

```
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\bfseries}
```

Here the fonts were:
Headings: Arial

Body text: Palatino Linotype

Headers: Palatino Linotype (bold)

**Here are my questions - I would really appreciate your help!**

1. Is it common for fonts to be different? KOMA-Script at least warns against mixing fonts - I don't want to do anything unusual, but I find it strange that the fonts are different.
2. Would it be advisable to change the header to the same font and bold (command see above)?
3. How could I change all elements to the same font?
   The following commands do not lead to the desired change...

```
\addtokomafont{part}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\normalfont\bfseries}
```

4. What other options/settings would there be for the font, or which font would you recommend to further reduce the page count?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    headheight=27.2pt,
    listof=totoc, 
    bibliography=totoc,
    listof=chapterentry,
    DIV=12,
    headsepline,
    plainheadsepline,
    twoside=semi
] {scrreprt} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %% newly added to make the font sans serif (8 pages shorter)

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %% to avoid indentation of paragraphs
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\normalsize\bfseries} %% The number and the word in Figure 1. XXX in bold
\setkomafont{caption}{\normalsize\bfseries} %% For table captions, the font in bold

\usepackage[automark,autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
%\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\bfseries} %%% Add this here?
%\addtokomafont{part}{\normalfont\bfseries}  %%%  Add this here?
%\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\normalfont\bfseries} %%% Add this here?
\ihead{\ifstr{\headmark}{}{\leftmark}{\headmark}}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{microtype} % line adjustment

\usepackage{caption} % for tables without caption and not in the directory with  \caption*{}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm not a user of the KOMA classes or packages, but I do know that the lmodern fonts are based on Computer Modern, which is, shall we say, "generous" in width.  Changing this to a clone of Times (which was designed for newspaper use, where space is limited) should make the type more compact and take less space, without resorting to sans serif.

Comment: This is a common problem, when writing a thesis, is how to reduce it.  A 10pt font for a thesis would be very acceptable when printed, although on a screen we tend to prefer a slightly larger size. Many publishers of academic works do that. The chapter headings will have a very small impact on number of pages. If one has 700 pages with 20 chapters. Reducing the chapter heading by 10 or 20% impact will be small.

Comment: ... continuing  So if possible give some statistics for the length of the thesis, Number pages in ToC etc, typicaDepending on the topic, I would leave the text in roman as studies show, this is perceived to be more authoritative. Brill is available and is used in their books. In the end most people use far too many subdivisions. Do yo need all the appendices, tables? Il page or 2.

Comment: sorry but a document with only \usepackage{lmodern} never will use arial or lucida. Your question about fonts make no sense.

Comment: A) What is the best approach to change to Times New Roman?
I am a bit lost with my packages. My approach would be

Delete:
i) \usepackage{lmodern}; 

ii) \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}; 

and add:

\usepackage{times}; 


I tried it. No errors.
As a result, the page number was already reduced.

However, fonts are:

Section Headings: Arial; 
Body Text: Times New Roman: 
Headers: Cambria; 
For Delimeters: Georgia (e.g. the ',' in 0,05):

Is this ok? Better way to do it?

Style-wise recommended to add:
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\bfseries}?

Comment: B) Statistics:

Thanks for the comment about appendices & tables etc. This was thoroughly discussed with my supervisor and we agreed on a lot of content reductions, so no further possibilities there.

Although not really my question, I am ofc happy to provide the stats ( with the fonts from my comment above):
- 26 pgs before main body of the dissertation, including header, toc, summary etc.
- 138 pgsmain body of the dissertation (introduction, methods, discussion,, limitations, outlook
- 5 pgs appendix
- 12 pgs bibliography
- 4 pages other, like CV;

On average, 100 chars per line

Comment: IMHO the fonts of a word documented that has been converted (with unknown method) from a pdf are not a good indicator for the fonts used by TeX to generate the PDF. Better information can be found in the log of the TeX run or in the PDF (most pdf viewers can list fonts, or just use command line tool `pdffonts`).

Comment: BTW: Why are you increasing the head height? Removing options `headheight=27.2pt` and `headsepline` reduces the number of pages by 1 in your MWE.

Comment: Off-topic: [Using `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` is not recommended.](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NoParIndent/) (linked page also available [in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_NoParIndent/)).